# SHFileOperation replace file dialog

Tags: file-management, shfileoperation

Currently, SHFileOperation has some confirm file replacement dialog boxes that ask the user if they would like to replace a file or not. I find these useful, but I would like to be able to modify the scenario in which they occur. Instead, I would like to compare the file contents first with a `bool compareFile()` function I wrote. Then, if the files are identical the file replacement dialog box will not come up. Assuming, I already have a working `compareFile()` function, is there a way for me to do this? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a callback with the shell using this interface.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7309/ICopyHook-implementation)